# How to alternate between calling code input and timer-based input and unit-test it with reactive programming

Tags: java, unit-testing, rx-java, reactive-programming

## Requirements

I'm trying to implement a class that calculates estimated time left for an operation to complete. I want to base the solution on **RxJava** - have the class expose the updated estimates as an Observable.

For the sake of the question, I've stripped my solution down to bare minimum, ditching the calculations and all other bells and whistles.

The core idea that remains is that we're listening to progress updates, but if there's no progress for a while (imagine a large number of files getting copied, and the app "choking" on a particularly large file), I would like the updates to keep on being emitted, periodically, while awaiting new info from the actual source.

(Obviously in the described sample scenario consuming code would observe the estimates getting worse and worse while the file is being processed).

I also want to unit test the solution.

## Simplified, compilable implementation (not working)

Here's my `Watcher` class (obviously I wouldn't need two Subjects if it was like that, but it mirrors the structure of the original, more complex implementaiton):

```
public class Watcher {
    public List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    public BehaviorSubject<String> retriever = BehaviorSubject.create();
    public BehaviorSubject<String> publisher = BehaviorSubject.create();

    public Watcher() {
        retriever
                // when no data is coming, start the timer
                .switchMap(
                        new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Observable<String> call(String s) {
                                return Observable
                                        .interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                        .map(new Func1<Long, String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public String call(Long tick) {
                                                return "tick " + tick;
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        })
                .doOnNext(
                        new Action1<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(String str) {
                                buffer.add(str);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .subscribe(publisher);
    }

    public void add(String str) {
        retriever.onNext(str);
    }

    public Observable<String> asObservable() {
        return publisher.asObservable();
    }
}
```

## Test code (failing)

Here's the test, which makes use of `TestScheduler` to simulate flow of time:

```
TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
TestSubscriber subscriber = new TestSubscriber();

Watcher watcher = new Watcher();
// adding this before the subscription occurs
// i'd also like to ensure that the observer "catches up" on whatever it missed
// - that's why I used PublishSubjects 
watcher.add("A");

watcher
        .asObservable()
        // this bit should get the whole thing running on TestScheduler
        // so that it reacts to artificial shifts of time
        .subscribeOn(testScheduler)
        .subscribe(subscriber);
watcher.add("B");
// this should get the timer going...
testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// and here I expect it to get disabled
watcher.add("C");

// over to the ticking timer
testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

## Expected vs. actual result

My **expected result** would be to receive: *A, B, a few ticks, C, a few ticks again.*

**What I'm getting** is all ticks! No A, B or C in sight. Neither in `testScheduler`, nor in `Watcher`s own buffer.

## Note

Funnily enough, the actual implementation suffers from the opposite problem: what I'm getting there is the actual input, and it's the ticks that are missing.

So apparently I didn't recreate it accurately in my simplified version. The error appears to be of similar nature though: for some reason switching between two sources doesn't work as I imagine it should.

## Question

What am I doing wrong? Do I misunderstand how `switchMap` is supposed to work? Do I misuse `TestScheduler` with its virtual time scheduling?

Apart from any possible mistakes on my part, is there a better, more idiomatic alternative that could get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Konrad, thanks for you detailed questions and the answer you posted. I am not quite sure if I completely understood your requirement, but it seems to me `startWith` should do the job.

Also, if you ask about "Rx idomatic", it is good practice derive your `Watcher` from `Transformer`. This makes it easier to reuse your method in Rx-chains.

Here is a complete code which does what I believe you intended to achieve. It is Java 8, which is more ergonomic to write Rx code.

```
package com.reactive;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Scheduler;
import rx.schedulers.TestScheduler;
import rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.Assert;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


// According to https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators#transformational-operators
// you should use transformers to implement your own observables
class Watcher implements Observable.Transformer<String,String> {

    Scheduler _scheduler;

    // As you already realized in your answer you need to specify the scheduler if you want to control the interval observable
    public Watcher(Scheduler scheduler) {
       _scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<String> call(Observable<String> retriever) {
        return retriever.switchMap(s ->
                // Create the sequence of ticks
            Observable.interval(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS,_scheduler)
            .map(tick -> "tick " + tick)
            // but prepend the actual signal from the retriever
            .startWith(s)
            );
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        BehaviorSubject<String> retriever = BehaviorSubject.create();

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        retriever.compose(new Watcher(testScheduler))
                .subscribe(s->results.add(s));

        retriever.onNext("A");
        retriever.onNext("B");
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        retriever.onNext("C");
        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        String result = String.join(" , ",results);
        Assert.that(result.equals("A , B , tick 0 , tick 1 , tick 2 , C , tick 0 , tick 1"),result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes, you got my requirements right. Good tips with `startWith` and `Transformer`. Nice to know I'm not doing anything wrong by passing the Scheduler around manually, I was pretty sure RxJava would have some magic abstraction for that :) Future readers please note that my answer pointed out some flaws in the posted code - that I was able to identify myself - along with necessary fixes which brought my code to the point where Peter helped me out

Comment: @KonradMorawski: It is actually good practice to "manually pass around Schedulers". I do not know about a reference for RxJava, but in Rx.Net the [design guidelines](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219)  5.4 suggest passing schedulers as arguments. Moreover, the contract 4.2 in the same document forces you to use the same scheduler for the `interval` observable as for the `retriever`. Thus, unless your `retriever` runs on the `computation()` scheduler, which is the default for `interval`, you need the possibility to specify the scheduler for your `Watcher`.

Comment: I see. And by the way, this wasn't only needed for *nested* Observables as I thought at first - ie. `throttleLast` operator also had to have the `TestScheduler` injected. Thanks for the link, it sheds more light on it. I googled around and it turns out RxJava doesn't have equivalent design guidelines as of now, apparently they're cooking something of that sort as part of their work on RxJava 2.0. At any rate I assume the good meta-practice would be to keep the Rx implementations consistent among platforms as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of answers hurt my feelings, but I bit the bullet and fiddled with it further, finally getting it to work as expected.

I'm not sure if my implementation is idiomatic, or correct (not in the narrow sense of arriving at the proper outcome, it does that - but I wouldn't swear if it's not forceful/hacky).

I took the time to lay it out and while I'd be happy if this was of help to anyone, I'm not exactly an expert (yet), and I'd be very grateful if someone offered their insights, possibly correcting some of my assumptions if they're off.

I fixed it in three fundamental steps.

#### 1.

I'm passing `testScheduler` (which always to use virtual time scheduling) into the nested `Observable.interval` manually now.

So, `TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();` was converted into a constructor argument now, and

```
Observable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

was replaced with

```
Observable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
```

Otherwise (apparently) `Observable.interval` keeps on running on its own default scheduler, which will keep on adding "ticks" to the buffer even when I'm debugging the test and it stops on a breakpoint.

Note that I already used `subscribeOn` to try and put the whole thing on the `testScheduler`:

```
watcher
    .asObservable()
    .subscribeOn(testScheduler)
```

The take-away is that `subscribeOn` doesn't affect nested observables: they will still operate on their default `Scheduler`, and you have to take care to override it manually. **If I'm misunderstanding this bit, penny for your thoughts!**

#### 2.

This bit:

```
.switchMap(
        new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<String> call(String s) {
                return Observable
                        .interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
                        .map(new Func1<Long, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public String call(Long tick) {
                                return "tick " + tick;
                            }
                        });
            }
        })
```

Still would leave me with only "ticks" in the buffer. The "A", "B", "C" were going missing (however the tick counter would reset back to 0 in places where I would expect A, B, C to come in).

In order to resolve it, I had to beef the implementation up like so:

```
.switchMap(
        new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<String> call(String s) {
                return Observable

                        // this preserves the original item 
                        // that caused the switch (the A, B or C)
                        .just(s)

                        // and here we say we want it followed by ticks
                        .concatWith(
                                Observable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
                                // <snip>
```

It does work now, however it's already nested quite deep. One of the main selling points of RxJava is that helps to avoid deep nesting, and flattens operations on data streams. **So, is there a better, flatter alternative? Am I doing it wrong?** This question still stands.

### 3.

At this point `watcher.buffer` would already contain *"A, B, tick 0, tick 1, tick 2, tick 3, tick 4, C, tick 0, tick 1"*. And I saw this was good.

However, my `TestSubscriber subscriber` was still missing the first "A" (the list `subscriber.getOnNextEvents()` starts with "B").

It's true that inserting "A" occured before the subscription:

```
watcher.add("A");

watcher
    .asObservable()
    .subscribeOn(testScheduler)
    .subscribe(subscriber);

watcher.add("B");
```

however, as explained in the comment in my question, this was deliberate, as `Watcher.publisher` (to which we subscribe) is a `BehaviorSubject` instance, and thus it shouldn't be a problem for it.

According to [the docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html), `BehaviorSubject` is a

> Subject that emits the most recent item it has observed and all
>   subsequent observed items to each subscribed Observer

So it's supposed to pass the most recent item it can recall to any newly subscribed Observer. I knew that "A" must have passed through the observable, because it was present in `watcher.buffer`. Why wouldn't `publisher` react to `subscribe` by passing the cached "A" first?

This took me a while to understand.

The answer seems to be: with time virtualization, we have to go all the way. If we don't push the clock manually, time is completely frozen and no operations are executed at all.

Hence it can be fixed quite simply:

```
watcher.add("A");

watcher
    .asObservable()
    .subscribeOn(testScheduler)
    .subscribe(subscriber);

// "go on, do your duty", as great Stannis would say
testScheduler.triggerActions();

// ^ if it didn't happen, "B" would be pushed in the exact same moment as "A",
// and as a result "A" is lost.
watcher.add("B");
```

`triggerActions` moves the world by a frame in `TestScheduler` universe, in this case flushing "A" down the chain. According to [the docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/TestScheduler.html#triggerActions%28%29) again, this method:

> Triggers any actions that have not yet been triggered and that are
>   scheduled to be triggered at or before this Scheduler's present time.

Only now the `subscriber` was on par with `buffer.watcher` as for the collected data. Champagne corks went off like fireworks (every coder knows the feeling of relief when the world is back in order) :)